# How do I get a tcolorbox to break on a page inside another tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, boxes

I like how `tcolorbox` breaks on the pages. But I have run into an issue. It won't break inside another `tcolorbox` it just pushes to the next page. Which made me test what would happen in the innter `tcolorbox` was longer than a page. It would just disappear.  Any help would be appreciated

[image]